# How to check if characters are repeating in a string

Tags: java

I have a list giving out a random word, that the user has to try to guess.

I need to prevent cheating, so i'm trying to check if there are 4 of the same characters in the word that they guess.

```
for(int i = 0; i < guess.length(); i++){

    for(int j = 0; j < guess.length(); j++){
        if(guess.charAt(i) == guess.charAt(j)){
            antiCheat++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your question? Does your implementation not work? (you could also start j at i so you don't double-check)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The game is wordle. I want to not let the player enter in a word that contains 4 of the same letter. When i run that code and enter a word like "wiwww", it comes up as 6 words are the same. I was wondering if my iteration is messed up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stream`:

- Split the word into a letters array and `stream` the resulting array.
- Collect the `stream` grouping by letters and collect downstream counting the number of elements.
- `Stream` the values of the resulting `map` and validate that all values are less than the max number of duplicate letters.

```
public static boolean check(String str, int max) {
    Map<String, Long> map = Arrays.stream(str.split(""))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                Collectors.counting()));
    return map.values().stream().anyMatch(count -> count >= max);
}
```

Test:

```
String str1 = "abcdefg";
String str2 = "abadafa";

int max = 4;

String msg = "Word '%s'" + " exceeds the limit of %s: %s";

System.out.println(String.format(msg, str1, max, check(str1, max)));
System.out.println(String.format(msg, str2, max, check(str2, max)));
```

Output:

```
Word 'abcdefg' exceeds the limit of 4: false
Word 'abadafa' exceeds the limit of 4: true
```